# How to add or remove spaces depending on user input (Ascii to hex, binary...)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I am trying to make it so you can convert user input (ASCII to hex, binary and more). My problem is when the user input has spaces I want the output also to have space and vise versa when there are no spaces also have no spaces.

```
    function asciiConverter(asciiInput) {
    var hexArray = [];
    var binArray = [];
    var decArray = [];
    for (var i = 0, length = asciiInput.length; i < length; i ++) {
        var hex = asciiInput.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
        hexArray.push(hex);
        var binary = asciiInput.charCodeAt(i).toString(2);
        binArray.push(binary);
        var dec = asciiInput.charCodeAt(i).toString(2);
        decArray.push(dec);
    }
    // /g is a global match with regex  
    var hexPrint = hexArray.toString().replace(/,20/g, " ").replace(/,/g, " ");
    document.write(hexPrint);
}
asciiConverter("123");
```

Output:  31 32 33

answered my own down below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own again:

```
var hexPrint = hexArray.toString().replace(/,20/g, " ").replace(/,/g, "");
```

change
    .replace(/,/g, " ");
to
    .replace(/,/g, "");